# How to fix malformatted special characters in Pop OS, that occoured after an system crash?

Tags: linux, fonts, character-encoding, crash, special-characters

This afternoon my computer (operating Pop OS!) was not reacting to keyboard or mouse interactions, I tried everything but couldn't find out why this happened. So I did a cold start, I assume the operating system had crashed somehow.

After the shutdown and start-up process, I realized that several characters, especially if they were special characters like : or * - signs, which are used at the login form password box, were displayed as a box. Image attached.

[image: This shows the issue in the Clock view.]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed the font display issue by doing the following**:

1. Reinstall the Pop OS - Theme (see: https://github.com/pop-os/gtk-theme#recommendations):

   sudo apt reinstall pop-theme
2. Enter the Shell's command launcher:

   Alt + F2
3. This will restart the Shell after you hit Enter:

   r

**Best regards.**